# Symfony2 Entity Cloning does not work

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, clone

I like to clone an Entity in Symfony2. It's working fine if I clone an Entity where this entity is a child. The following code isn't working. It clones the entity but I get a duplicate key error

Code in my controller:

```
$id = $request->get('id');
$entity = $orSessionVersionRepository->find($id);
// A new Version must be created!
// Clone OrSessionVersion entity
$cloneEntity = clone $entity;
$em->persist($cloneEntity);
$em->flush();
```

Error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO or_session_version (version, name, duration, occupancy_standard, condition_weekday, condition_start, condition_end, creator, remarks, edit_reason, min_age, max_age, status, type, color, created, modified, or_session_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [2, "Session 1", "04:00:00", "75", "a:7:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:5;i:6;i:6;}", "08:00:00", "16:30:00", "admin", null, null, 16, 100, "final", "default", "#1429e6", "2013-10-25 14:25:14", "2013-10-25 14:25:14", "41"]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2-41' for key 'or_session_id_version'
```

Someone can help?

Comment: Why do you need to clone the entity?

Comment: Does "$em->persist($entity);" work either?

Comment: You need to unset the id or another unique property or you will run into a constraint violation.

Comment: Unsetting the Id doesn't solve the problem. I clone entities in more than one action and there it's working fine. Probably it isn't working because doctrine gives a Proxy object instead of the real object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also clone child entity.

Try to add this method on your parent entity :

```
public function __clone() {
    if ($this->id) {
        $this->child = clone $this->child;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am too facing the same issue but it does not fixed my issue. please assist. I have a single entity which one i want to clone to a another row

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a cloned entity should be detached from the ORM.

Can you try to do

```
$id = $request->get('id');
$entity = $orSessionVersionRepository->find($id);

$cloneEntity = clone $entity;

$em->detach($cloneEntity); 
$cloneEntity->setId(null);

$em->persist($cloneEntity);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: This solution isn't working. I clone entities in more than 1 action and there it's working fine. I implemented a __clone public function in each entity so relationships get cloned to. Is it possible that the clone function isn't working because doctrine gives a Proxy object instead of the real object?